# Geolocation doesn't work on safari and ios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I used Geolocation service.it works on Chrome ,Firefox and Android.but it doesn't work on Safari and my website crashes.first I should check that this service has enabled after.for checking it I implemented this code.

```
 navigator && navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(function (PermissionStatus) {
            if (PermissionStatus.state == 'granted') {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function (position) {
                        latLng.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                        latLng.lng = position.coords.longitude;
                        callback(latLng);
                    });
            }
```

What should I do?

also I used this code

```
 `   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function(){alert('success')},
                function(){alert('error')}
            );`
```

I get error in safari but it is working good in chrome and firefox

Comment: *navigator.permissions* is [*experimental*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/permissions#Browser_compatibility) so not widely supported, write defensively.

Comment: So What should I do for safari for getting location of user from browser?

Comment: See [*MDN: Geolocation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API), it's notoriously unreliable as users may block you from accessing their location, and IP location is extremely problematic.

Comment: In my iPhone I enable the location service,but I doesn't work yet